# How to prevent duplicates entries in for each loop when inserting in laravel? - Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a function in controller which fetches all products based on Auth::id:

```
    $products = DB::table('products')
              ->where('created_by_id', Auth::id())
              ->get();
```

Then has a for each loop as follows which inserts and update:

```
    foreach($products as $key => $product){
                        $previous_product = Product::create((array) $product);
                        $previous_product->save();
                        $previous_product->update(['created_by_id' => $reseller_id->reseller_id]);
                }
```

Which work perfectly, but the problem I am facing is products are duplicated twice instead of duplicated once. as shown on below image:

[image]

What I have tried to do is to use replicate() method instead of create() but I got null on replicate and the problem still persists.

Any help given to resolve my issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use insertOrIgnore method  with query builder It will fix your issue.

```
  DB::table('products')->insertOrIgnore($arrayOfProducts);
```

Comment: for this one I get Call to a member function save() on int

Comment: Yes that`s right!

Comment: Okay, then how will I update a record when I want to do so?

Comment: You could Chain ->ignore(); method after updating your records with query builder.

Comment: Okay, let me try that

Answer (score 0):

I would give `replicate` another shot:

```
$products = Product::where('created_by_id', Auth::id())->get();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->replicate()
        ->fill(['created_by_id' => $reseller_id->reseller_id])
        ->save();
}
```

The code you have doesn't appear that it would cause 2 new records to be inserted, though the `save` call you have is unneeded since `create` creates the record (saves it) and `update` calls `save`.

Comment: I get this error Call to undefined method stdClass::replicate()

Comment: the first line in my example is using the `Product` Model, not Query Builder

Comment: Okay I tried that way, now nothing is replicated, I think this is my Product model related problem

Comment: I dd($products) from $products = Product::where('created_by_id', Auth::id())->get(); and gets empty collection and Auth::id() returns id which is stored in created_by_id

Answer (score 0):

You can also `updateOrCreate()` method for the operation so that way you're sure to be only updating if the record exists or create. Here's a link https://laravel-news.com/firstornew-firstorcreate-firstor-updateorcreate

Comment: I tried this but it still gives me the same results I described in my question

Comment: You might want to paste your updated code cause I can't see where you used this method in your code

Comment: foreach($products as $key => $product){
            $previous_product = Product::updateOrCreate((array) $product);
            $previous_product->update(['created_by_id' => $reseller_id->reseller_id]);
        }